# How to select first record prior/after a given timestamp in KDB?

Tags: database, kdb, q-lang

I am currently just pulling in all records 1min leading up to the timestamp (e.g. if the timestamp I'm interested in is `2014.04.14T09:30`):

```
select from Prices where timestamp within 2014.04.14T09:29 2014.04.14T09:30, stock=`GOOG
```

However, this is clearly not very robust. Sometimes the previous record may be at `09:25am` and then the query returns nothing. Sometimes the query may return hundreds of records if there have been a lot of price changes, even though all I need is the last record returned.

I know this can be done with an asof join, but want to avoid it for the time being as `Prices` is simply too big at present.

I am also interested in doing the same, but in finding the first record **after** a given timestamp.

Note also that `Prices` is a **splayed** table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select last record before the given timestamp:

```
q)select from Price where stock=`GOOG,i=last i,timestamp<2014.04.14T09:30
```

Select first record after the given timestamp:

```
q)select from Price where stock=`GOOG,i=first i,timestamp>2014.04.14T09:30
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if `Prices` is splayed? Can `aj` work directly on splayed tables? I had thought not, so was taking huge amounts of time reading a portion of `Prices` into memory before using `aj`. That was my rationale for avoiding `aj`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `asof` or `aj` to get the performance kdb+ is known for. The bigger Prices is, the more reason for doing so.

I would question your logic for avoiding `aj`. `aj` and `asof` use the `bin` operator which is binary search and hence more performant than scanning the timestamp column.

Let's create your table and run the solution from the other answer:

```
Prices:([]stock:`g#1000000?`GOOG,9?`4;timestamp:asc 2014.04.14+1000000?0t;price:1000000?100f,size:1000000?100j)
q)\t do[1000;select from Prices where timestamp<2014.04.14T09:30,stock=`GOOG,i=last i]
10205
```

We can make this a lot better by reordering the constraints:

```
q)\t do[1000;select from Prices where stock=`GOOG,timestamp<2014.04.14T09:30,i=last i]
2030
```

But nothing will beat this:

```
q)\t do[1000;Prices asof `stock`timestamp!(`GOOG;2014.04.14D09:30)]
9
```

By the way, you are using datetime in your question, which is deprecated, so I've replaced it with timestamp. This has no impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Few more things to remember while using `aj`:

- in-memory prices - the table should be `` `g#sym `` and `time` sorted within `sym`
- on-disk prices - `` `p#sym `` and `time` sorted within `sym`

Also in case of partitioned/splayed tables, using the `where` constraints (except the `date` in the date-partitioned table) can severely impact the performance.